# Dwolla payment integration in Mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, payment-gateway, braintree, dwolla

I want to integrate Dwolla Payment into my App, a marketplace app. Initially planned to integrate Braintree, but we need to wait for the approval till the app development completion(then only submit for the review). So that my client instructed me to check the Dwolla. I could not find any mobile SDK from Dwolla.

Comment: https://github.com/Dwolla/dwolla-ios

Comment: @PPL It is deprecated.

Comment: I got a reply from Dwolla developer page.  

"Hello, We do not have SDKs for Android or iOS. The primary interaction with Dwolla happens from your backend server and not a mobile client, therefore we offer SDKs in a subset of server-side programming languages. ((https://developers.dwolla.com/pages/sdks.html)) 
When someone wants to login via your mobile application, your application will simply forward the request to the server that will then send the authenticated request to Dwolla. Your server can then tell your client if it was successful or not."

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that dwolla deals with direct transfers (ACH) and doesn't handle cards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dwolla api directly into your backend server for the bank to bank transfer